# Android App Ported to Blackberry 10 doesn't use correct language translations

Tags: android, translation, blackberry-10

So I have an Android app that I am porting to Blackberry 10. On Android it translates to French perfectly fine, but when ported to Blackberry there is no French. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. To anyone who may come across the same issue. The Blackberry 10 Android Runtime does not support regional localization, i.e. fr-rCA will not work but fr will work.